# What is the probability of taking 15 free throws in a game and making 10 in a row?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

What is the probability of taking 15 free throws in a game and making 10 in a row given that each shot has a 50% probability of going in?

I have simulated this problem but I also want to confirm the results with an analytical approach.

This appears to be a problem that fits with the binomial distribution but the approach I have taken doesn't match the simulation. Here is what I did.

When taking 15 shots, there are only 6 possible ways you can make 10 in a row multiplying that times the probability of making 10 out of 15:

\begin{equation}
(15 - 10 + 1)*{{15 \choose 10} * 0.5^{10} * (1-0.5)^{5}} = 0.55
\end{equation}

A probability of 50% seems way to high and it doesn't match with my simulation. My intuition tells me that the probability should be a fraction of

\begin{equation}
{{15 \choose 10} * 0.5^{10} * (1-0.5)^{5}}
\end{equation}

Because the set of outcomes where 10 shots in a row are made out of 15 is less than any 10 out of 15.

The other way to think about this is to consider what fraction of the total possible outcomes that the distinct 10 in a row outcomes make.

\begin{equation}
(15 - 10 + 1) / 2^{15}
\end{equation}

But this also doesn't match up with my simulation and it doesn't translate to probabilities other than 1/2.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Additional threads with related (or even the same) questions can be found by searching our site for [probability row](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+row).  They indicate the probability you seek is $112/2^{15}\approx 0.003417969$. By looking at when the streak begins, I can find $2^5 + 2^4 + 2\times 2^3 + 2^2\times 2^2 + 2^3\times 2^1 + 2^4\times 2^0$ = $112$ distinct ways in which it can occur, each with probability $2^{-15}$.

Comment: Thanks @whuber! That is really helpful. Can you explain how you came up with \begin{equation}f_{p,8}(0,25) = 18p^8 - 17p^9 - 45p^{16} + 81p^{17}-36p^{18}\end{equation} in the question this is a duplicate of?

Comment: That's the solution of the dynamic program I describe there. It is obtained using algebraic manipulation, treating $p$ as a variable rather than as a numeric value.